# Is there a "model theoretical" proof of Solovay's Stationary Splitting Theorem?

Tags: set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

Consider Solovay's Stationary Splitting Theorem: In $\operatorname{ZFC}$ every stationary subset $S$ of some cardinal $\kappa$ with uncountable cofinality  can be partitioned into $\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)$ disjoint, stationary subsets.

His original proof relied on forcing, but later a more elementary proof was found which uses nothing more than clever, but basic, calculations.

**My question:** Is there also a "model theoretical" proof of this result in the style of Assaf Rinot's blogpost about [c.c.c. forcing without combinatorics](http://blog.assafrinot.com/?p=843)? I thought that I've once encountered such a proof, but so far wasn't able to find a reference or remember its main idea.

Comment: How about this: Let $\kappa$ be a cardinal of uncountable cofinality and $S$ a stationary subset of $\kappa$, $M$ a countable elementary submodel of $H(\kappa^+)$ with $S\in M$. Then in $M$ Solovay's theorem is true so we can partition $S$ into $\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)$ disjoint stationary sets. By elementarity we can do it in $H(\kappa^+)$ as wanted. $\square$ :-P

Comment: @Asaf Is this one of these moments where someone else impersonates you, Asaf? ;-)

Comment: Why would you say that? This is a very typical thing for me to say... :P